# Return value is undefined after reassigning a variable value

Tags: javascript

```
var player = { score: 3 };

function doStuff(obj) {
  obj = {};
}

player = doStuff(player);
```

This is a very simple question which I'm sure has a very simple answer but I can't seem to logic my way through it. The return value for `player` at the end returns `undefined`. This is my thinking of what is happening here. `var player` is defined and initialized to an object. The value of `player` is then reassigned to the value of `doStuff(player)` function. Is the value of `player` simply undefined because there is no return value from the function call itself?

Comment: The answer is Yes!

Comment: Sounds like figured this out yourself.

Comment: Yes, if you add return obj to your function you will get empty object.

Comment: Yes, you got it correct.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I thought as much. Just wanted to cement my logic and make sure I'm thinking of things correctly. Not sure why I get down voted for asking a basic question since it doesn't seem too conducive to beginners

Answer (score 3):

Yes the value is `undefined` because your function doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

True.

Example:

```js
var player = { score: 3 };
console.log(player);        // player is now Object { score: 3 }

function doStuff(obj) {
  obj = {};
}

player = doStuff(player);    // player is now replaced by an undefined object

console.log(player)
```